Puppetear doesn't show iframe with google map in js
I have html template that comst from FE to node js BE. This template incudes iframe with google map in it. I need to render this template, make screenshot and send file back to FE. Template wokrs fine when I open it manually, but when puppetear openes it (via headless: false), I see only white screen. All other content in template puppetear renders correctly.
HTML tempalte also has some variables in it, and I need to change them with actual values, but this part works just fine, I wrote it just for you guys not be confused with variables parametr in my code
Also have this error in console
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

HTML template example

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"/>
    <meta charset=UTF-8>
    <title>Gabelstapler+map image template</title>
</head>

<style>

.map-trans {
transform: perspective(900px) rotate3d(180,-61,0,22deg);
}

.map-trans iframe {
filter: invert(1) grayscale(1);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1) invert(1);
}

.stapler-img {
position:absolute;
    margin-top: -430px;
    margin-left: -150px;
}


</style>



<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="map-trans">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps?hl=de&q=73249&t=k&output=embed" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
    </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>


I wrote such service to use puppetear
My screenshot service
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

class ScreenshotService {
  constructor() {
    this.browser = null;
  }

  async initialize() {
    this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  }

  async takeScreenshot(htmlContent, viewport, extension = 'png') {
    const page = await this.browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport(viewport);
    await page.setContent(htmlContent, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    await page.waitForSelector('iframe');
    await page.waitForSelector('img');
    const screenshot = await page.screenshot({ type: extension, fullPage: true });
    // await page.close();
    return screenshot;
  }

  async close() {
    await this.browser.close();
  }
}

export default ScreenshotService;


How I use it
  async makeScreenshot(template, variables, extension) {
    const htmlContent = this.renderHTML(template, variables);
    await this.screenshotService.initialize();
    const screenshot = await this.screenshotService.takeScreenshot(htmlContent, variables.viewport, extension);
    // await this.screenshotService.close();
    return screenshot;
  }


Found an answer
Just need to update headless to true
this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true});

